# Existe a possibilidade de comparar schema entre bancos diferentes no SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, comparação

Possuo vários BD diferentes, e preciso compara os Schemas delas, mas fazer isso de forma manual pode passar algo despercebido. Para contexto vou utilizar de banco de dados de proporção menor dos que trabalho. Imagem [aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loA7J.png).

Como pode se perceber na imagem, tenho dois bancos de dados, a **base_forte** e a **base_comparacao**.

***Problema:***
Ambos possuem a tabela **dbo.aluno**, porem, na **base_comparacao** ela possui colunas **ID, Nome e RA**. Já na **base_forte** as colunas são **ID, Nome e Email**, ou seja, difere o campo **RA** e **Email**.

Outro Ponto que se diferem é que na **base_comparacao** contem a tabela **dbo.disciplina**, o que não tem no outro banco. Da mesma forma na **base_forte** contem a tabela **dbo.curso** que não contem na outra.

***Duvida:*** é possível realizar essa comparação entre duas bases diferentes? Se sim, como? Preciso de algo que retorne as diferenças dos Schemas, **NÃO** dos dados contidos.

Em outros fóruns li sobre o `tablediff` mas não me atendeu, ou entendi errado o que ele realiza.

***UPDATE:*** achei algumas ferramentas que fazem isso (**dbForge Schema Compare** e **Open DBDiff**), gostaria de saber se há uma ferramenta dentro do próprio SQL Server que faça isso sem precisar de baixar outra aplicação.

Comment: Encontrei na rede dba: [How can I compare the schema of two databases?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95236/how-can-i-compare-the-schema-of-two-databases). Na primeira resposta o autor diz para baixar [ssmsboost](http://www.ssmsboost.com/) e gerar o script dos dois bancos e usar WinMerge(Desconheço) para comparar os scrips.

Comment: tem super bom o https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/

Comment: tem umas versão de teste

Comment: vlw a dica pessoal, vou olhar essas ferramentas ... Mas o que queria saber é se há algo nativo do próprio SQL Server que faça isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use esse Script e adapte para a sua necessidade:

```
use master
go

DECLARE @Server1 VARCHAR(100) ='[LD38\SQLEXPRESS2005].'; --include a dot at the end
DECLARE @DB1 VARCHAR(100) = '[TestDB]';
DECLARE @Table1 VARCHAR(100) = 'Customer';

DECLARE @Server2 VARCHAR(100) ='[LD38\SQLEXPRESS2005].'; --include a dot at the end
DECLARE @DB2 VARCHAR(100) = '[TestDB2]';
DECLARE @Table2 VARCHAR(100) = 'Customer';

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @SQL = 
'
SELECT Table1.ServerName,
       Table1.DBName,
       Table1.SchemaName,
       Table1.TableName,
       Table1.ColumnName,
       Table1.name DataType,
       Table1.Length,
       Table1.Precision,
       Table1.Scale,
       Table1.Is_Identity,
       Table1.Is_Nullable,
       Table2.ServerName,
       Table2.DBName,
       Table2.SchemaName,
       Table2.TableName,
       Table2.ColumnName,
       Table2.name DataType,
       Table2.Length,
       Table2.Precision,
       Table2.Scale,
       Table2.Is_Identity,
       Table2.Is_Nullable
FROM   
    (SELECT ''' + @Server1 + ''' ServerName, 
           ''' + @DB1 + ''' DbName,
           SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) SchemaName,
           t.Name TableName,
           c.Name ColumnName,
           st.Name,
           c.Max_Length Length,
           c.Precision,
           c.Scale,
           c.Is_Identity,
           c.Is_Nullable
    FROM   ' + @Server1 + @DB1 + '.sys.tables t
           INNER JOIN ' + @Server1 + @DB1 + '.sys.columns c ON t.Object_ID = c.Object_ID
           INNER JOIN sys.types st ON St.system_type_id = c.System_Type_id AND st.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
    WHERE  t.Name = ''' + @Table1 + ''') Table1 
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT ''' + @Server2 + ''' ServerName, 
           ''' + @DB2 + ''' DbName,
           SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) SchemaName,
           t.name TableName,
           c.name ColumnName,
           st.Name,
           c.max_length Length,
           c.Precision,
           c.Scale,
           c.Is_Identity,
           c.Is_Nullable
    FROM   ' + @Server2 + @DB2 + '.sys.tables t
           INNER JOIN ' + @Server2 + @DB2 + '.sys.columns c ON t.Object_ID = c.Object_ID
           INNER JOIN sys.types st ON St.system_type_id = c.System_Type_id AND st.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
    WHERE  t.Name = ''' + @Table2 + ''') Table2
    ON Table1.ColumnName = Table2.ColumnName
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Table1.ColumnName IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, Table1.ColumnName
'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Criei 2 Bancos com tabelas com nomes iguais e colunas diferentes:
Resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma idéia:
Com o Script eu criaria uma Stored Procedure, receberia como parâmetro as tabelas, faria uma lista com as tabelas do banco de compararia todas as tabelas do seu DB e faria um resumo bacana.
Se fizer isso compartilhe conosco! Será muito útil!